# c# listbox i have trouble with

Tags: c#-4.0

I created a list in a button ADD:

```
{
List <string> Names = new List<string>();

Names.Add(textBox1.Text);
textBox1.Text = " ";
}
```

I created another button SHOW NAMES and i want these names I entered in the list, to be listed in the listbox? How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to move that first line outside of the button click method, because if you declare the list inside the method, it will be gone once that method returns.

For your SHOW NAMES method, if all you want to do is *display* the list, you could use a TextBlock instead of a listbox, and it will be a little easier:

```
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.text = string.Concat(Names);
```

Comment: thank you but... nothing happened, I mean instead of those names in textblock i get collection, collection, collection...

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger to verify that `Names` actually contains strings, or make sure that the class of `Names` is actually `List<string>`, and not a generic list.  You could also try a different overload of the Concat method, like `string.Concat(Names.ToArray())`.